# c#: Convert object to a generic list

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-conversion

I've got a data structure in which a variable is of type `object`. However, I know during runtime this object will be definitely a `List<T>`, where `T` should cover multiple cases (e.g., `int`, `string`, ...). In the following code, I'd like to use `List<T>`-specific functionality, such as Linq functions.

With the following check, I make sure, it's a list:

```
if (constantExpression.Value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) 
{
    // Want to use Linq here
}
```

Is this possible? Unfortunately, I've found nothing helpful on the Web.

Comment: Explicitly declare as a  (List<T>)?

Comment: Type cast it into your List<T>.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but needs a lot of awkward reflection. Since you don't know `T` at compile-time, you cannot really cast your `object` to a `List<T>`. So you have to find the correct linq extensions via reflection and use `MakeGenericMethod` to create the correct generic version.

Comment: @AndrejHafner how do you cast to a _generic_ type? if you don't know `T` at compile-time, you cannot cast.

Comment: What sort of linq functions are you wanting to use afterwards? I'm struggling to think what sort of LINQ operations you might do with it that don't involve knowing what the `T` is...

Comment: if you just have a small number of possible types for `object` you could potentially declare it as `dynamic` and then create methods for each of your types and let the dynamic overload resolution then work out what code to run based on the runtime type. Whether this will work for you or not I don't know.

Comment: @Chris Actually, for the moment, I just want to call ToString() on each list items, so `object` is fine for me. Your suggestion works well for me. Thanks!

Comment: If that's all you want then the answer Konamiman has given is the way to go, not my suggestion of `dynamic`. `dynamic` has much more overhead than just a few casts does.

Comment: @Chris Ok. Thank you for this comment. I'll go with the solution below proposed by Konamiman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok for you to handle your list as a `List<object>()` you can do the following:

```
var listOfObjects = ((IEnumerable)constantExpression.Value).Cast<object>();
```

That's far from perfect but it's probably the best you can get if you don't want to resort to using reflection or using `dynamic`, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: This works fine. So does the solution with dynamic. Thank you!